# Spring MVC - alternative for displaytag ? (Jakarata EE 10 + Spring 6.1)

Tags: java, spring

My project is quite old and is currently working with Spring MVC and JSP. We are in the process of migrating it to the latest version of Spring MVC. However, I am facing compatibility issues with my DisplayTag jar and Jakarta EE 10, displaytag internally using javax.

Could you please suggest an alternative for displayTag? I have tried using JSF, is that a good solution? I need to do exporting data and rendering JSP data, pagination, sorting etc.